# How to preform method call of the same class in a different method?

Tags: objective-c

I have an address book class, and in this class I have a `searchName` method, now I want to add a `removeName` method that would remove name from address book(while i was writing it i thought it's pretty clear..just sharing).

Anyway, what I though is to use `preformSelector:@selector(searchNames)` but im getting error in this line..this is my code:

```
//method to search address cards
-(NSMutableArray *) searchName:(NSString *) someName{

    NSMutableArray *namsFound = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (AddressCards *addressCard in book){

        if ([addressCard.name rangeOfString:someName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            [namsFound addObject:addressCard];
        else if ([addressCard.email rangeOfString:someName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            [namsFound addObject:addressCard];
        else if ([addressCard.country rangeOfString:someName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            [namsFound addObject:addressCard];
        else if ([addressCard.workPlace rangeOfString:someName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            [namsFound addObject:addressCard];
    }

    return [namsFound count]? namsFound : nil;
}
```

I have to use this method declaration that return `BOOL`:

```
-(BOOL) removeName:(NSString *)theName{

    if ([theName performSelector:@selector(searchName:)] > 0){
        for (AddressCards *card in book)
            [book removeObject:theName];
        return YES;
    }

        else
            return NO;
}
```

This is how i'm trying to test it in main.m:

```
AdressBook *myBook = [[AdressBook alloc] initWithName:@"Family Address Book"];

if([myBook removeName:@"nir"] == YES)
            [myBook list];
        else
            NSLog(@"Not in address book");
```

im getting thread 1 SIGBRT on this line: for (AddressCards *card in book)

Please help me to figur this out.
cheers

Comment: I am not understanding your exact problem, kindly explain.

Comment: As stated below you need to use `@selector(..)` to convert a character name into a `selector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why should the string object respond to `-searchName:`? call it on self, withe the string as argument. and there seem to be no reasone for `-performSelector:` here. Also you want to check for the count of the array, not only the pure existence.

```
-(BOOL) removeName:(NSString *)theName{

    if ([self searchName:theName]){
        for (AddressCards *card in book)
            [book removeObject:theName];
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

---

OK, I had another look on search name. you return nil, if the array is empty. so you dont need to call `-count`.

---

try

```
-(BOOL) removeName:(NSString *)theName{
    NSArray *results = [self searchName:theName];
    if (results){
       [book removeObjectsInArray: results];
       return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: still dosen't work..i tried your code, maybe I need to change something in main? @vikingosegundo

Comment: im getting thread 1 SIGBRT on this line: `for (AddressCards *card in book)` @vikingosegundo

Comment: where does book come from?

Comment: from this class, its nsmutablearray that contain address cards of type AddressCard(another class) @vikingosegundo

Answer (score 0):

You have a method named `searchName`

> class I have a searchName method,

but you are calling `searchNames` here, change it to `searchName:`

```
preformSelector:@selector(searchNames:)//one : as it takes one argument
```

Comment: sorry that was a syntax mistake, but it's not the prob..@Anoop Vaidya

Comment: @Nir: kindly tell what is your exact problem

Answer (score 0):

That's because performSelector doesn't have any return value. Why can't you just call the method normally?

```
if ([self searchName:theName]) // do stuff
```

Note that you were not passing the param to searchCards: too, and that you should not compare it's value to 0 like you were (the method returns nil if nothing was found).

EDIT:

You need to call the method on self, not on theName.

Comment: i'm also trying to figure out why i can call the method normally...you have any idea why i cant? xcode wont let me @Marcelo Fabri

Comment: Try to call the method on self, and not on theName. I edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

you should use preformSelector:@selector(searchNames:) as you are having one parameter in that method

and if you want return value from that function other than object, you can use NSInvocation